# Why "type check" behaves differently on Swift and Objective-C?

Tags: swift, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

```swift
class A: NSObject {
    let value: Int
    
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class B: NSObject {
    let value: Int
    
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class Main: NSObject {
    @objc func printValue(_ instanceA: A) {
        print("Value: \(instanceA.value)")
        print("instanceA is A? \(instanceA is A)")
        print("instanceA is kind of A? \(instanceA.isKind(of: A.self))")
    }
}

Main().perform(NSSelectorFromString("printValue:"), with: B(value: 2))
```

If we run the above code, we can get this:

```
Value: 2
instanceA is A? true
instanceA is kind of A? false
```

we can see `instanceA is A` is different from `instanceA.isKind(of: A.self)`, do you know why?

Comment: I don't see the Objective-C material anywhere in this question. Where is it?

Comment: `is A` is checked at *compile time.* You should see a warning “'is' test is always true” from the compiler.  The compiler cannot know that you cheat and pass an instance of B to a method expecting an instance of A.

Comment: Yeah, you've skirted around the static type system by making a dynamic method call using the wrong types. This is still possible (although confusing, and you should avoid it), but you'll need to stick to run-time type checks like `isKind(of:)`, `type(of:) == ___`, etc. Better yet, you should fix the underlying hack. What exactly were you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why "type check" behaves differently on Swift and Objective-C?

Because these are two different languages.

Objective-C class analysis is done via [introspection](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introspection/Introspection.html#:%7E:text=Introspection%20is%20a%20powerful%20feature,themselves%20as%20objects%20at%20runtime.), and performed at runtime. [`[NSObject isKindOfClass:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418511-iskindofclass) is one of the introspection methods which also does its job at runtime, thus the result of this operation is unknown until execution of your program gets to the point of where this method is called.

Swift, unlike Objective-C is statically typed and it gives the language the luxury of compile-time type check. All types in a Swift program are (supposed to be) known at compile time, so the code doesn't need to double-check them again when it comes to runtime (it's still required when it comes to subclassing, however, but that's irrelevant to the scenario you provided).

For your specific example, I would say it's unfortunate side effect of the Swift and Objective-C interoperability. When compiling a project with mixed Swift and Objective-C code neither Objective-C nor Swift code is actually converted to another language. Both worlds keep following their own rules and compiler just generates interface for them to communicate. Thus when calling this function:

```swift
Main().perform(NSSelectorFromString("printValue:"), with: B(value: 2))
```

You actually delegate the execution to the Objective-C world, where the runtime blindly sends `"printValue:"` message with *a pointer to some Objective-C object*. Objective-C can do that even without playing around with `performSelector:` family of methods:

```objc
#pragma mark -

@interface TDWA : NSObject {
@public
    int _value;
}

- (instancetype)initWithValue: (int)value;

@end

@implementation TDWA

- (instancetype)initWithValue:(int)value {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _value = value;
    }
    return self;
}

@end

#pragma mark -

@interface TDWB : NSObject {
    long _another_value;
    const char *_c_string;
}

- (instancetype)initWithValue: (int)value;

@end

@implementation TDWB

- (instancetype)initWithValue:(int)value {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _another_value = value;
        _c_string = "Another imp";
    }
    return self;
}

@end

#pragma mark -

@interface TDWMain : NSObject

+ (void)printValue: (TDWA *)instance;

@end

@implementation TDWMain

+ (void)printValue:(TDWA *)instance {
    NSLog(@"Value: %d", instance->_value);
    NSLog(@"Is A? %s", [instance isKindOfClass:[TDWA class]] ? "Yes" : "No");
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    TDWB *instance = [[TDWB alloc] initWithValue:20];
    [TDWMain printValue: instance];
    /* Prints:
     * Value: 20
     * Is A? No
     */
    return 0;
}
```

Moreover, despite types of ivars in the classes don't match, and for `TDWB` the ivar is not public, it's still accessible through `TDWA` interface. Thanks to C-legacy, if you know the memory layout of a class, you can access values of its Ivars no matter whether they are private or not. With Swift the same would never be possible, because you cannot pass an argument to a method which expects different type of parameter:

```swift
class A: NSObject {
    let value: Int
    
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class B: NSObject {
    let value: Int
    
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class Main: NSObject {
    @objc class func printValue(_ instanceA: A) {
        print("Value: \(instanceA.value)")
        print("instanceA is A? \(instanceA is A)")
    }
}

let instance = B(value: 20)

Main.printValue(instance) // Compile-time error - Cannot convert value of type 'B' to expected argument type 'A'
```

Since you delegate delivering of this message to Objective-C's [`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418764-performselector) it's not a problem there and the message is successfully delivered. Thanks to runtime introspection, `[NSObject isKindOfClass:]` is also able to properly check the class.

For Swift, however, checking that parameter of type `A` is `A` doesn't make much sense. Swift does not allow to pass an incompatible value as argument, so i *think* that `is` operator does nothing here and the compiler just optimises it to a `true` expression at compile time. However if you try to perform this check against a subclass of `A`, it would fail, because Swift would actually have to go through the class hierarchy:

```swift
class C: A {}

class Main: NSObject {
    @objc class func printValue(_ instanceA: A) {
        // prints true only if instanceA is of type C
        print("instanceA is A? \(instanceA is C)")
    }
}
```

---

### Bonus Analysis

I actually decided to look at [SIL](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/SIL.rst#copy-value) listing for the given case to confirm my assumption and here are the results:

##### Scenario 1. "Apparent" type check

I removed all irrelevant parts from the printValue function and left only type check operator with a variable to read it (to avoid this part be discarded altogether):

```swift
@objc func printValue(_ instanceA: A) {
    let fooBar = instanceA is A
}
```

This results in the following SIL code for the function:

```
// Main.printValue(_:)                                                                                         
sil hidden @$s4main4MainC10printValueyyAA1ACF : $@convention(method) (@guaranteed A, @guaranteed Main) -> () { 
// %0 "instanceA"                                 // user: %2
// %1 "self"                                      // user: %3
bb0(%0 : $A, %1 : $Main):
  debug_value %0 : $A, let, name "instanceA", argno 1 // id: %2                                                
  debug_value %1 : $Main, let, name "self", argno 2, implicit // id: %3                                        
  br bb1                                          // id: %4                                                    
                                                                                                               
bb1:                                              // Preds: bb0                                                
  %5 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int1, -1          // user: %7
  br bb2                                          // id: %6                                                    

bb2:                                              // Preds: bb1                                                
  %7 = struct $Bool (%5 : $Builtin.Int1)          // user: %8                                                  
  debug_value %7 : $Bool, let, name "fooBar"      // id: %8                                                    
  %9 = tuple ()                                   // user: %10
  return %9 : $()                                 // id: %10                                                   
} // end sil function '$s4main4MainC10printValueyyAA1ACF'
```

There is quite a lot of stuff happening here, but we are most interested in the first basic block `bb0`. As you can see it transfers control to the next block `bb1` with an unconditional terminator called. So the type check doesn't happen here at all.

##### Scenario 2. Real type check

Now let's look what happens when Swift actually needs to check the type:

```swift
class C: A {}

class Main: NSObject {
    @objc func printValue(_ instanceA: A) {
        let fooBar = instanceA is C
    }
}
```

Here is what the Swift compiler now emits for the SIL code of the function:

```
// Main.printValue(_:)
sil hidden @$s4main4MainC10printValueyyAA1ACF : $@convention(method) (@guaranteed A, @guaranteed Main) -> () { 
// %0 "instanceA"                                 // users: %10, %5, %4, %2                                    
// %1 "self"                                      // user: %3                                                  
bb0(%0 : $A, %1 : $Main):
  debug_value %0 : $A, let, name "instanceA", argno 1 // id: %2                                                
  debug_value %1 : $Main, let, name "self", argno 2, implicit // id: %3                                        
  strong_retain %0 : $A                           // id: %4                                                    
  checked_cast_br %0 : $A to C, bb1, bb2          // id: %5                                                    

// %6                                             // user: %8
bb1(%6 : $C):                                     // Preds: bb0                                                
  %7 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int1, -1          // user: %9 
  strong_release %6 : $C                          // id: %8
  br bb3(%7 : $Builtin.Int1)                      // id: %9                                                    
  
bb2:                                              // Preds: bb0                                                
  strong_release %0 : $A                          // id: %10
  %11 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int1, 0          // user: %12                                                 
  br bb3(%11 : $Builtin.Int1)                     // id: %12                                                   
                                                                                                               
// %13                                            // user: %14
bb3(%13 : $Builtin.Int1):                         // Preds: bb2 bb1
  %14 = struct $Bool (%13 : $Builtin.Int1)        // user: %15
  debug_value %14 : $Bool, let, name "fooBar"     // id: %15
  %16 = tuple ()                                  // user: %17
  return %16 : $()                                // id: %17
} // end sil function '$s4main4MainC10printValueyyAA1ACF'
```

As you can see `bb0` is now actually terminated with a conditional type checking `checked_cast_br`. And it either goes to `bb1` or `bb2` block depending on the results.

Comment: Thanks for you details answer, by the way, do you know how arguments are passed in performSelector:withObject:? Here is the details question https://stackoverflow.com/q/73366054/4050529

Comment: This answer deserves way more upvotes.